# How to show number without rounding off numbers

Tags: c#, rounding

I have this number: 1234.5678 (as a text)

I need this number as double, with only 2 numbers after the dot

But without Round the number

in 1234.5678 - i get 1234.57

in 12.899999 - i get 12.90

How I can do it ?

Comment: I'm unclear. Do you want the result to be rounded or not. You say you don't want rounding. But you show rounded results. Are those the results you want or results you're getting that you're dissatisfied with?

Comment: @Nosredna: He wants truncation, not rounding.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to get what you want like this:

```
number.ToString("#0.00")
```

Comment: never used the pound sign thing. is that the part that controls rounding?

Comment: @Jared: No, it an optional digit in a picture mask.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply by 100, take floor() of the number, divide by 100 again.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't post the results you *wanted*, but I assume you want truncation, so that you'll see 1234.56, and 12.89.  Try:

```
decimal d = 1234.89999M;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Truncate(d * 100) / 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you can't represent these numbers exactly as doubles, so converting, rounding, and then reprinting as text results in a loss of precision.

Use 'decimal' instead.

Comment: NO, he's concerned with truncating rather than rounding.  That doesn't have anything to do with the internal representation.

Answer (score 1):

Take this floating point arithmetic!

```
var num = "1234.5678";
var ans = String.Empty;
if( !String.IsNullOrEmpty(num) && num.Contains('.') ) // per comment
{
  ans = num.Substring(0, num.IndexOf('.') + 3);
}
```

Comment: you could at least add the checks for not-exists and end-of-string :>

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
string rawVal = "1234.5678";
System.Math.Floor((double.parse(rawVal)) * 100) / 100;
```

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't work?

```
        double d = 1234.5678;
        double rounded =Math.Round(d, 2);
```